# How to change bitrate with nreco functions using textbox?

Tags: c#, textbox, bitrate, nreco

I'm trying to write a converter in C # using Nreco.VideoConverter. I've never had any experience with these before. I started researching this area because I was asked at work. My problem is; I can change the bitrate value in video converter. If you have a combobox or a specific value. But, if there is any value to enter from the textbox, I cannot adapt the code accordingly. Below is the code I use. Please help.

Code is;

```
  if (comboBox2.Text == "_1000kbit")
    {
    if (comboBox1.Text == "mp4" || comboBox1.Text == "mp4 1280 x 720 16 : 9" || comboBox1.Text == 
    "mp4 640 x 350 16 : 9" || comboBox1.Text == "mp4 720 x 540")
    {
     var ffmpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
     ffmpeg.ConvertMedia(VideoPath, null, MusicPath, null, new ConvertSettings()
       {
       CustomOutputArgs = "-b:v 1000k -bufsize 1000k"
       });
       }

         }
```

but ı want do this;

```
 if (comboBox2.Text == "_1000kbit")
          {
           if (comboBox1.Text == "mp4" || comboBox1.Text == "mp4 1280 x 720 16 : 9" || 
            comboBox1.Text == "mp4 640 x 350 16 : 9" || comboBox1.Text == "mp4 720 x 540")
           {
              var ffmpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
             ffmpeg.ConvertMedia(VideoPath, null, MusicPath, null, new ConvertSettings()
            {
          CustomOutputArgs = "-b:v"+textBox1.Text+"k -bufsize"+textBox1.Text+"k"
          });
          }

             }
```

So is it possible? how can i do it if possible?
Because when I type it it says `ffmpeg` can't find the argument.
By the way, I set the `textbox` value to int.
Please help for this.
Thank You.

What I have tried:

ı want do this; but is it possible or true I have no idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 CustomOutputArgs = String.Format("-b:v {0}k -bufsize {0}k", textBox1.Text);
```

Edit: Explaining problem in code
Your CustomOutputArgs were turning out to be: **-b:v1000k -bufsize1000k**
instead of **-b:v 1000k -bufsize 1000k** (Notice the spaces)

Comment: In the code I've written this I have also fixed resolutions; Can I put resolutions like 1280: 720 into the code? E.g:  CustomOutputArgs = String.Format("-s ega-b:v {0}k  -bufsize [0}k", textBox4.Text